# I do not see my cluster under Amazon EKS after creation via eksctl

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I created an Amazone EKS Cluster using eksctl script. The creation was OK but I cant see any clusters in Amazone EKS Services Cluster page, and I cant see any EC2 instances.
What is the problem ?!

```
2021-03-18 11:03:10 [ℹ]  waiting for the control plane availability...
2021-03-18 11:03:10 [✔]  saved kubeconfig as "/root/.kube/config"
2021-03-18 11:03:10 [ℹ]  no tasks
2021-03-18 11:03:10 [✔]  all EKS cluster resources for "test-cluster" have been created
2021-03-18 11:03:10 [ℹ]  adding identity "arn:aws:iam::<aws_client_id>:role/eksctl-test-cluster-nodegroup-lin-NodeInstanceRole-Y6JRBHNK5M7I" to auth ConfigMap
2021-03-18 11:03:10 [ℹ]  nodegroup "linux-node" has 0 node(s)
2021-03-18 11:03:10 [ℹ]  waiting for at least 2 node(s) to become ready in "linux-node"
2021-03-18 11:03:42 [ℹ]  nodegroup "linux-node" has 2 node(s)
2021-03-18 11:03:42 [ℹ]  node "ip-192-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal" is ready
2021-03-18 11:03:42 [ℹ]  node "ip-192-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal" is ready
2021-03-18 11:03:43 [ℹ]  kubectl command should work with "/root/.kube/config", try 'kubectl get nodes'
2021-03-18 11:03:43 [✔]  EKS cluster "test-cluster" in "eu-central-1" region is ready
```

Comment: Most likely you are in a different region. Did you try switching to **eu-central-1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have occasionally looked at the resources in the AWS Console while pointing to a wrong region and seeing no resources as I would expect.
From your run it looks you created the cluster in `"eu-central-1"`. Make sure you're pointing to the correct region in the AWS console.